# While using genymotion getting a blank screen with EULA acceptance

Tags: android, genymotion

[While using Genymotion for personal use, I am getting a blank screen with EULA acceptance.How to achive this problem ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ganm.png)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can try this workaround:

When on the black window, make sure the **window has focus**, then:

- Press **TAB twice**
- Press **SPACE**
- Press **TAB twice**
- Press **SPACE**

This should click on the checkbox to accept the EULA then click on the validate button

be aware that legally **you are accepting the EULA agreement without reading it**...

Comment: I cracked myself up doing this. Any idea why this happens at all?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was changing the 'High contrast settings'. On Windows 10 I selected 'High Contrast #1', which showed the screen.